# What is opposite of append() function in python?

Tags: python

Recently I was learning python,and I want to use the function that is opposite of append() function.How can I use the function insert an element in the first position of the list.Thank you!

Comment: Is a function that inserts an element in the first position of a list really the opposite of `list.append()`? Wouldn't the opposite be something like, "remove the last element from a list and return it"? The more clearly you ask your question the more likely you are to get a good answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Prepend doesn't exist, but you can simply use the `insert` method:

```
list.insert(0, element)
```

Comment: it works,Thank you very much!